# Access Conditional Formatting for continuous form on individual records

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a continuous form that list times that samples were taken and levels of different chemicals in those samples.  I want to format the cells to show when a chemical level is out of range.  My problem is, that they change for each sample time.  .3 is way too high for a 10 hour sample, but is fine for 30 hours.  Below is an example of what my continuous form looks like.

```
Sample Time      Lactics      Sugar
10 hour           .085        15.2
20 hour           .125        12.8
30 hour           .345        8.4
40 hour           .405        4.2
50 hour           .415        1.9
```

So I want to say "if Lactics > .2 at 20 hour then make the cell red" and so on for each time period and each component I am tracking.  How can I set this up with VBA?

Comment: Check out conditional formatting http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/change-the-appearance-of-a-control-by-using-conditional-formatting-HA010208133.aspx

Comment: @Remou I can say, make it red if > .3, but I don't know how to say red if > .3 and 10 hours, red if > .35 and 20 hours, red if > .4 and 30 hours, red if > .45 and 40 hours....

Comment: Conditional formatting set to 'expression is' will work for me.  I just wish there was a better way to manage the code.  This will work though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a table to hold your "out of range" rules.

```
Sample Time Lactics_limit
10 hour                .3
20 hour               .35
30 hour                .4
40 hour               .45
50 hour                 ?
```

Then base your form on a query which joins your original table to the value_limits table, with a calculated field, `lactics_flag`, which indicates when the value is out of range.  And base your conditional formatting on `lactics_flag`.

```
SELECT
    y.[Sample Time],
    y.Lactics,
    y.Sugar,
    IIf(y.Lactics > v.Lactics_limit, True, False) AS lactics_flag
FROM
    YourTable AS y
    INNER JOIN value_limits AS v
    ON y.[Sample Time] = v.[Sample Time];
```

Compare the simplicity of that approach with the complexity of an `Expression Is` list you would need to express those same rules:

```
([Sample Time]="10 hour" And [Lactics]>0.3) Or ([Sample Time]="20 hour" And [Lactics]>0.35) Or ([Sample Time]="30 hour" And [Lactics]>0.4) Or ([Sample Time]="40 hour" And [Lactics]>0.45) Or ([Sample Time]="50 hour" And [Lactics]>?)
```

Another advantage of this approach is that it's easier to maintain your rules when they are stored in a table instead of as conditional formatting expressions in a form.  And the rules could be easily re-used for other forms or reports.

If you don't have rules for every `[Sample Time]`, you could leave them out of the `value_limits` table and use a `LEFT JOIN` in the query.

Comment: ahHA!!  That is what I was looking for!  I needed something to be able to change/update the numbers more frequently.  This will work great!  So much better than editing all the conditional formatting expressions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Expression Is wih a list of values:

```
 ([sample]=10 And [Lactics]>=0.2) Or ([sample]=20 And [Lactics]>=0.35)
```

[image: Conditional]