# Highlight field background in continuous form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an Access continuous form. I would like to change the forecolor of a specific record's field.

I have the field to highlight from the FieldModified field. So for example  FieldModified = "Converted". Converted being a field on my form.

I would like to change the color of the "Converted" field, and do this for each record in the form.

I thought this code would work, but I get an error on Me.[FieldModified].ForeColor. And I need to do this for each record in the form.

Code:

```
    Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim fldName As String
    fldName = Me.FieldModified.value
    If (Not IsNull(fldName)) Then
     Me.[fldName].ForeColor = vbRed '<--doesn't recognize fldName value
    End If
End Sub
```

Updated code but it gives me an error 438 saying object doesn't support this property or method. But the form does highlight fields on the form but it highlights more then the one field "fldName"

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim rstForm As String
Dim fldName As String
Set rstForm = Me.ChangedData.Form.Recordset

Do While Not rstForm.EOF
fldName = Me.FieldModified.value    
If (Not IsNull(fldName)) Then
    Me.Controls(fldName).ForeColor = vbRed '<--doesn't recognize fldName value
End If

rstForm.MoveNext
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: In your code `fldName` is defined as a String, which has no `.ForeColor` property. Perhaps you just need to change `Me.[fldName].ForeColor = vbRed` to `Me.Control(fldName).ForeColor = vbRed`

Comment: Thank you. How would I do this for each record in the continuous form?

Comment: You can't `Set` a `String`, `rstForm` should be declared `As Recordset`.

Comment: I changed the Dim statement to Dim rstForm As Recordset but I'm still getting the method or data member not found

Comment: The only way to achieve this is with **Conditional Formatting**, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39294487/how-can-i-conditionally-format-textbox-border-on-continuous-form or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13937493/access-conditional-formatting-for-continuous-form-on-individual-records

Comment: I couldn't get the conditional formatting to work with Me.Controls(fldName)

Comment: I have the code sort of working. I updated it in my question. What's going on is it's highlighting more than one field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set the default format for the control. Every copy of the control in the continuous form uses this format. To format by a condition (`fldName = Me.FieldModified.value`) you need **Condtional Formatting** as Andre told you or use the detail-sections paint event (see update on bottom)

In conditional format wizard, you can create a condtion with`Expression Is`and`[Converted].Name =  [FieldModified]`for each control of the form that should be highlighted, if its name matches`FiledModified`. In Ms Access expressions you can't use`Me`, just omit it .

You can use VBA to format all controls with [FormatConditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.formatconditions) by code. If you want to modify an existing condition use`.Modify`instead of`.Add`

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()
  Dim ctl As Access.Control
  For Each ctl In Me.Controls ' loop through all controls of form
      On Error Resume Next ' Not all controls can have conditional format (e.g. labels). To save the check of control type, we ignore errors here
      ctl.FormatConditions.Add(acExpression, , ctl.Name & ".Name=[FieldModified]").BackColor = vbRed 'add o format condition to control if possible, else an error is raised but ignored
      If Err.Number Then 'show errors
          Debug.Print "Error: " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.description & " in Control: " & ctl.Name & " Type is " & TypeName(ctl)
          Err.Clear 'reset error to catch next
      Else
          Debug.Print "FormatCondition added to Control: " & ctl.Name & " Type is " & TypeName(ctl)
      End If
  Next ctl
  On Error GoTo 0 ' turn on errors again, maybe add an error handler (On Error Goto MyErrHandler)
End Sub
```

***Update:***
You can use the`Details_Paint`event of the form to format same control different per record. This enables conditional format for controls without`FormatConditions`property like labels, buttons.

```vb
Private Sub Detail_Paint()
Dim c As Access.Control

For Each c In Me.Detail.Controls
    If c.Name = Me.FieldModified.Value Then
        c.ForeColor = vbRed
    Else
        c.ForeColor = vbBlack
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried using both of your codes and it didn't work for me. I think it's because I'm trying to compare the Fields name

Comment: @MaxineHammett Sorry I forgot to change`Field1`to`FieldModified`. Code is updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a `String` variable like this, `fldName` is an identifier holding a `String` value.. not an *identifier* - in `Me.ControlName`, both `Me` and `ControlName` are *identifiers*.

But not all hope is lost! You can use a `String` to pull a `Control` object from a form!

All form controls should exist in the form's `Controls` collection, keyed by name:

```
Me.Controls(fldName).ForeColor = vbRed
```

Comment: You are so awesome! But how would I do this for each record in the continuous form?

Comment: Oh, I've no idea - I never use Access, so Access forms are a bit foreign to me. There's no code in the question that gives me any hint of a notion of there being more than a single instance of any given control, so... I'll try to find an Access expert.